# Item Level Permission for a view in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, wss-3.0, item-level-permissions

I have created a Custom List and have 3 different view within.First 2 views are Standard Views(One of them is my default view) and the 3rd one is a Spreadsheet or Data view.In the spreadsheet view,I want to give permissions according to the below logic:

If an item has status "Completed",no action can be performed by any users(except Read only) but the admin user will be able to perform all action.In short Edit functionality will be disabled for all the users except the Admin when status is completed.

Can this be possible using Sharepoint 2013?
Please suggest me if there are any other approaches of implementing this requirement as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using designer workflow, which can set item level permission.

In the workflow, everyone except Admin will be granted only read permission based on the status value.

Reference:
http://spcycle.blogspot.sg/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html